# Average, RMS and number of zero corssings array of numbers c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

My assignment is to find the average value, RMS value and number of zero crossings (positive to negative or negative to positive) in 3 arrays for different wave forms,

Then too apply the same procedure on a rectified version of each of the waveforms, where all values in the array will turn positive. I must use a function for each.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE1 80
#define SIZE2 62
#define SIZE3 29
double findAverage(short array[], int size);
double findRMS(short array[], int size);
unsigned findZeroCrossings (short array[], int size);
int main()
{
// array of values in cosine waveform //
short cosine[SIZE1] = {
    32767, 32666, 32364, 31862, 31163, 30273, 29196, 27938, 26509, 24916,
    23170, 21280, 19260, 17121, 14876, 12539, 10126, 7649, 5126, 2571,
    0, -2571, -5126, -7649, -10126, -12539, -14876, -17121, -19260,     -21280,
    -23170, -24916, -26509, -27938, -29196, -30273, -31163, -31862, -32364, -32666,
    -32767, -32666, -32364, -31862, -31163, -30273, -29196, -27938, -26509, -24916,
    -23170, -21280, -19260, -17121, -14876, -12539, -10126, -7649, -5126, -2571,
    0, 2571, 5126, 7649, 10126, 12539, 14876, 17121, 19260, 21280,
    23170, 24916, 26509, 27938, 29196, 30273, 31163, 31862, 32364, 32666
};
// array of values in triangle waveform //
short triangle[SIZE2] = {
    15500, 14500, 13500, 12500, 11500, 10500, 9500, 8500, 7500, 6500,
    5500, 4500, 3500, 2500, 1500, 500, -500, -1500, -2500, -3500,
    -4500, -5500, -6500, -7500, -8500, -9500, -10500, -11500, -12500, -13500,
    -14500, -15500, -14500, -13500, -12500, -11500, -10500, -9500, -8500, -7500,
    -6500, -5500, -4500, -3500, -2500, -1500, -500, 500, 1500, 2500,
    3500, 4500, 5500, 6500, 7500, 8500, 9500, 10500, 11500, 12500,
    13500, 14500
};
// array of values in sawtooth waveform //
short sawtooth[SIZE3] = {
    -24000, -22000, -20000, -18000, -16000, -14000, -12000, -10000, -8000, -6000,
    -4000, -2000, 0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 12000, 14000,
    16000, 18000, 20000, 22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000
};
// calculate and display all the average values //
cout << "Average value in cosine waveform : " << findAverage (cosine, SIZE1) << endl;

cout << "Average value of triangle waveform : " << findAverage (triangle, SIZE2) << endl;

cout << "Average value of sawtooth waveform : " << findAverage(sawtooth, SIZE3) << endl;

// calculate and display all the RMS values //
cout << "\nRMS value of cosine waveform : " << findRMS (cosine, SIZE1) << endl;

cout << "RMS value of triangle waveform : " << findRMS (triangle, SIZE2) << endl;

cout << "RMS value of sawtooth waveform : " << findRMS (sawtooth, SIZE3) << endl;

// calculate and display number of zero crossings //
cout << "\nNumber of zero crossings of cosine waveform : " << findZeroCrossings(cosine, SIZE1) << endl;

cout << "Number of zero crossings of triangle waveform : " << findZeroCrossings(triangle, SIZE2) << endl;

cout << "Number of zero crossings of sawtooth waveform : " << findZeroCrossings(sawtooth, SIZE3) << endl;
 }

 double findAverage(short array[], int size)
 {
 int    i;
 int sum = 0;
 double average;
 for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
 {
    sum += array[i];
 }
 average = double(sum) / size;
 return average;
 }

 double findRMS(short array[], int size)
 {
 int i;
 double sumsquared;
 double RMS;
 sumsquared = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
    sumsquared += array[i]*array[i];
 }
    RMS = sqrt((double(1)/size)*(sumsquared));
    return RMS;
 }

 unsigned findZeroCrossings(short array[], int i)
 {
 if ((array[i] >= 0) && (array[i + 1]) < 0)
 i++;
 if ((array[i] < 0) && (array[i + 1] >= 0))
 i++;
 return i;
 }
```

My source code returns no issues from c++ however it is not returning the correct results for the number of crossings.

for the number of crossings I get : 80 , 62 , 29

Any ideas on how to fix this? And how I would go about rectifying each waveform in c++?

Comment: `findZeroCrossings` takes the size of the array and adds 0, 1 or 2 to it (depending on the random values that appear after the end of the array). Which seems odd.

Answer (score 2):

Move the computation of `RMS` outside the for loop. Compute it after gathering all the squares.

Instead of:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
   sumsquared += array[i]*array[i];
   RMS = sqrt((double(1)/size)*(sumsquared));
   return RMS;   // This returns after getting the square of just the
                 // first term.
}
```

use:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sumsquared += array[i]*array[i];
}
return sqrt((double(1)/size)*(sumsquared));
```

Comment: I have edited the coding and that seems to produce more realistic values for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Darren08 your problem was that the `return` statement stops the loop, that's why it should be after the loop to happen when all's done. If R Sahu's answer fixes your problem, please accept it as the correct answer to close this question.

Comment: @coyotte508 I understand that now thank you.  It answers part of my problem, the main problem is the if statement of my zerocrossings function, I cannot somehow manage to return the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your zero crossing function:

```
 unsigned findZeroCrossings(short array[], int i)
 {
     if ((array[i] >= 0) && (array[i + 1]) < 0)
         i++;
     if ((array[i] < 0) && (array[i + 1] >= 0))
         i++;
     return i;
 }
```

and you call it like that:

```
findZeroCrossings(sawtooth, SIZE3)
```

So what do you do? You take the size of the array in the second parameter, then you check for a zero crossing **after** the end of the array, which is very wrong.

For example, if you have an array of size 1000, you'll return 1000 or 1001 zero crossings, because you return the size you were given plus maybe 1 (`i` in your code).

What you should do is something like this:

```
 unsigned findZeroCrossings(short array[], int size)
 {
     int zeroCrossings = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i + 1 < size; i++) {
         if ((array[i] >= 0) && (array[i + 1]) < 0)
             zeroCrossings++;
         if ((array[i] < 0) && (array[i + 1] >= 0))
             zeroCrossings++;
     }
     return zeroCrossings;
 }
```

Learn to use loops better, and differentiate between the different variables!

Comment: This works well thank you! however my assignment states that the first and last sample of the arrays should be interpreted as consecutive. I believe this will change the number of zerocrossings for the sawtooth waveform to be 2, instead of 1 as your function gives. Sorry i should have said @coyotte508

Comment: That's something you should be able to do yourself @Darren08